# How to fetch and embed the latest YouTube video from a channel, but redirect to YouTube on clicking the play button?

Tags: youtube, youtube-javascript-api

I am trying to embed the latest YouTube video from a channel. However, the video has disabled playback on third-party websites. Rather than displaying the error message to the user, I would like to simply display the video so that when the user clicks to play the video, they are redirected to watch on YouTube. How can I achieve this?

Alternatively, I would be fine with fetching the title, image, and URL and displaying them as HTML, if this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

It'd be better to just put the image and URL.

Given that you know your video id:

All URLs are in the format

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=<video id>
```

Each video has 4 corresponding images which are

```
http://img.youtube.com/vi/<video id>/0.jpg
http://img.youtube.com/vi/<video id>/1.jpg
http://img.youtube.com/vi/<video id>/2.jpg
http://img.youtube.com/vi/<video id>/3.jpg
```

`0.jpg` is a full size image, while the other three are thumbnails.

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem. I don't know the video ID. I know the ID of the channel. I want to dynamically fetch the latest video within a channel.

Comment: But that's helpful to know the URL structure of those images!

Comment: Ahh got it. So the question isn't even about the image/url, it's about pulling the latest video from a channel. You should clarify that in your question, Sorry to say I don't know much about the YouTube API.